Example of an even nonnegative bandlimited Schwartz function with nonnegative Fourier transform
I am looking for an example of an even Schwartz function $f$ such that $f \geq 0$, $\widehat{f} \geq 0$ and $\text{supp}(\widehat{f}) \subset [-1, 1]$, i.e., $\widehat{f}(\xi) = 0$ for $|\xi| >1$. The gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ satisfies all the properties except that it does not have a finite support. Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Hint: take the inverse Fourier transform of a convolution of a non-negative bump function with support in a suitably small interval with itself.
